# Is it good practise to minimize the number of foreign keys in database design

Tags: database, database-design

I have almost no experience with backend and database design, so I'm wondering, is it good practise to minimize the number of foreign keys in your database?

For example, let's consider logging on a search website:

```
USER --hasA--> SESSION --makes--> QUERY
```

In this case, there is a one-to-many relationship between the user and the session, and the session has a one-to-many relationship with query. It makes sense for session to have a foreign key for the user_id and for query to have a foreign_key for the session_id, but should the query table have a foreign key for the user_id? Why or why not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to minimize them? These enforce referential integrity and without them you will be in a place where you database can hold inconsistent data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `user_id` to `QUERY` would make the database redundant. That's why this is mostly bad-practice. It can be necessary as a performance optimization in extreme cases (rarely).

Minimizing the number of foreign keys is usually not a design goal because it does not help with anything.

The typical design goal is to have a clean database that models the business domain most naturally. In that sense, don't add the `user_id` to `QUERY`. But absolutely *do* add all FKs which make sense. This does provide clear and noticeable benefit for development cost and application reliability.

Comment: I guess I was asking not so much as to whether it's a design goal, but a good heuristic to abide by. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider extreme example to show consequences of such an approach. What would happen if one applied this solutions to all tables in the model?
Let's expand your model with some extra tables and look what that brings with it:

[image: draft]

Is it now clear how does it relate to proper db schema?